# How do i set a default comboBox Text?

Tags: c#, combobox

How do i set a default text for my combobox on loadup, such as "Select Something". I tried this on the Form Load

```
 comboBox1.Text = "Select Something";
```

But that didnt work. Any help?

Comment: @GrantWinney I could do that, but im trying to make it so that the option isnt visible for people to click on :p

Comment: `comboBox1.Items.Insert(0, "-Select Something-");`

Comment: @GrantWinney On one of my old projects I got it to work, i honestly dont remember how I did it, but it worked. Ill definitely do this is no other solutions arise :p

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working for me, so you must be setting the text before binding the combobox to your data source.  In the following test code it works if you have the cb.Text = "Test"; running after the databinding of the combobox, and displaying the same symptoms you are seeing if you are setting prior to the databind.

Consider the following code where there is just a combobox defined on the form (cb).  If you move the last line to the top, it will display the symptoms you are seeing.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable tb = new DataTable();
    tb.Columns.Add("Value");
    tb.Rows.Add("Combo Box Item");
    cb.DisplayMember = "Value";
    cb.ValueMember = "Value";
    cb.DataSource = tb;

    cb.Text = "Select Something";
}
```